# Swift 3: How to save recording from AVAudioRecorder to assets library?

Tags: url, swift3, avfoundation

I'm trying to let user to record sounds and save the sounds into assets so that I can use it for UILocalNotification's soundname.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are trying to do is unfortunately not possible. The `UILocalNotification.soundName` property refers to a sound file in the app bundle. The app bundle is signed so it cannot be modified by the running app.